# single quotes (apostrophe) arround letter to print to screen C++

Tags: c++

I am doing an assignment and I was wondering how we get single quotes around a letter writing to the screen. I would like to write: The lower case equivalent of 'A' is 'a'. not double quotes like " but single '. Please C++ only, no C.

> cout << " The lowercase equivalent of  " << mychar << " is " << 
>   input << endl;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single quotes should work just fine inside double quotes:

```
cout << " The lowercase equivalent of '" << mychar << "' is '" << input << "'" << endl;
```

Comment: I would like to put them arround for example 'mychar' and 'input' not the string. have any idea? I know that is not the way because I keep getting errors but that is the general idea

Comment: If you use `std::string` (which manages memory for you) you can make a function:  `std::string add_ticks(std::string s) { return "'" + s + "'"; }`

Comment: 3. convert the character and display the results in the following format with single quotes around  the original and converted characters as shown: 
The lowercase equivalent of 'A' is 'a'- this is my problem I have completed my code to make any upper case Character change to lower case but I cant figure out how to put the single quotes into the code when it prints out.

Comment: Or, yet:  `std::string add_ticks(char c) { return "'" + std::string(c,1) + "'"; }`

Comment: ... to work out the above, look at the [constructors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) for `std::string`

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << " The lowercase equivalent of \'" << mychar << "\' is \'" << input << "\'" << endl;
```

Should work. Single quotes need to be escaped by the backslash.

Comment: Not inside double quotes they don't.

Comment: yes, you're right, the backslashes are not required in this case (but it's working with backslashes too)